# How to create self defined token in Django Token Auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

Can we create a self-defined token in the Token Auth in Django?

Currently, we are creating a super-user and generating a token for that super-user. But there are several environments and we want to keep the token same for all environments. Hence, a self-defined token is needed.

For example, if we create token using Token Auth

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

we first create a superuser, then we create a token using django-admin.

```
Authorization:Token 8b000baba908hh7cf0618d492896e7b4bd6c9ce3
```

Here, I want to define my own token which will be saved in the same table.

Comment: something like JWT (?)

Comment: not like JWT i guess, in JWT user requests the token 1st. i want to keep token permanent. i have updated the description, if that helps. @Alviandoh

Comment: so technically if we "steal" the method of rest_framework Token generate their own token, and save it in your table. and then create custom backend based on their backend. It'd be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you would like to have the same token for superuser in many environments (different servers)? If that's true, then you can try to override the method for automatic creation the tokens.

How to generate the tokens:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#generating-tokens

DRF AuthToken code
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/models.py

Based on the above the example code can be (not tested):

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.is_superuser:    
            Token.objects.create(user=instance, key="superuser_key")
        else:
            Token.objects.create(user=instance) # use generated key
```

**Important** Please do not hardcode the token in the code, you can use for example python-decouple package to handle it as env variable.